# How to connect a signal with int parameter to a slot with enum parameter WITHOUT using lambdas in QT5?

Tags: c++, qt, lambda, signals-slots

I'm trying to connect the signal `currentIndexChanged(int)` from `QComboBox` to a slot from my class that receive an enum, like `Foo::mySlot(EnumFoo)`.

I know that all these ways DON'T work:

1. `connect(cb, &QComboBox::currentIndexChanged, foo, &Foo::mySlot);`
2. `connect(cb, static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(EnumFoo)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), foo, &Foo::mySlot);`
3. `connect(cb, &QComboBox::currentIndexChanged, foo, static_cast<void (Foo::*)(int)>(&Foo::mySlot));`

because in C/C++, `int` never cast implicitly to an enum type. The opposite is true, I think if my signal has an enum parameter, I can connect it to a slot with int parameter without problem.

I know how to solve this question using lambda function:

`connect(cb, &QComboBox::currentIndexChanged, [=](int i){ foo.mySlot(static_cast<EnumFoo>(i)); });`

Is there any way to solve this problem WITHOUT lambda function?

**EDIT:** Using the solution I proposed, I'm connecting Foo::mySlot this way.

```
LambdaWrapper *lw = new LambdaWrapper;
lw->connect(cb, static_cast<void(QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), [=](int i){ foo.mySlot(static_cast<EnumFoo>(i)); }, foo);
```

and I don't have to worry about disconnection stuff anymore. Just have to manage `lw` lifespan.

Comment: There are numerous ways to avoid the lambda function, of which there is write your own enum containing class, provide a "wrapper" signal/slot that just forwards its argument with a `static_cast` and does exactly the same as your lambda.... Are you offended by the lambda (I'm sure it didn't mean it that way), are you used to not-so-strongly types languages, or do you have the misconception that this is going to ruin ~performance~?

Comment: No, it's just curiosity. Indeed, I have a little doubt: I don't understand well if and in which situations we should release the `QMetaObject::Connection` before destruct the QComboBox or the Foo class using `QObject::disconnect(const QMetaObject::Connection&)` overloaded member. Or if we can just ignore it. If I can ignore this disconnect stuff, no problem using lambdas. On the other hand if I have to deal with it, maybe I should use a wrapper slot as pointed by you.

Answer (score 2):

Use an intermediate slot that takes an int and calls the other slot function directly.

```
class Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT:

public slots:
    void IndexChanged(int intParam);    
    void mySlot(EnumFoo fooType);
};    

void Foo::IndexChanged(int index);
{
    EnumFoo fooType = <static_cast<EnumFoo>(index);
    mySlot(fooType);
}

connect(cb, &QComboBox::currentIndexChanged, foo, &Foo::IndexChanged);
```

Comment: I've thought the same solution, unfortunately we have to create another slot, but this can solve. If I don't have to manage the manual disconnect stuff when using the lambda solution, I don't have a reason not to use them. But I don't still understand well when I have to disconnect connections to lambdas manually and when I can just ignore them.

Comment: Each time the signal is called, the lambda function will be executed, so if you don't want that to occur, you'd need to disconnect the signal.

Comment: So I always have to disconnect this connection whether some object called inside the lambda (and captured BY REFERENCE) goes out of scope or, if created dynamically, its pointer is deleted. If I don't do that, my app will crash or segfault by sure because if the signal is triggered, the lambda is executed but its call an inexistent instance of an object. Right?

Comment: If an object is likely to go out of scope within the lambda, the compiler should warn you of this. If the object to which you connect the lambda is deleted, the connection will automatically be removed.

Comment: I understand that a connection is removed when an object that emits the signal connected to the lambda is deleted. But what happens if I connect a signal from an object to a lambda and I capture a pointer dynamically allocated of another object and call member from this object INSIDE the lambda? And if I somehow delete this object and then trigger the signal to call this lambda? I didn't test it but I'm sure that the program will crash.

Comment: Yes, you can cause it to fault in that situation, if the pointer is still valid, but the object pointed to has been deleted. Passing by value will ensure objects are copied into the lambda. If you need a pointer, then perhaps a smart pointer would be better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a small class to automate this disconnect stuff handling.

lambdawrapper.h

```
class LambdaWrapper : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit LambdaWrapper(QObject* parent = 0);
    virtual ~LambdaWrapper();

    template<typename Func1, typename Func2>
    void connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender,
                 Func1 signal,
                 Func2 slot,
                 QObject* receiver = 0) {
        connections << QObject::connect(sender, signal, slot);
        helperConnection(receiver);
    }

private slots:
    void disconnectReceiver(QObject* obj);

private:
    void helperConnection(QObject* obj);
    QList<QMetaObject::Connection> connections;
    QObjectList receivers;
};
```

lambdawrapper.cpp

```
LambdaWrapper::LambdaWrapper(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) { }

LambdaWrapper::~LambdaWrapper() {
   for (const QMetaObject::Connection& c : connections)
       QObject::disconnect(c);
}

void LambdaWrapper::disconnectReceiver(QObject *obj) {
    if (receivers.contains(obj)) {
        QList<const QMetaObject::Connection*> toRemove;
        const int n = receivers.size();
        for (int i=0; i<n ; ++i) {
            if (receivers.at(i) == obj) {
                disconnect(connections.at(i));
                toRemove << & connections.at(i);
            }
        }

        receivers.removeAll(obj);
        for (const QMetaObject::Connection* c : toRemove)
            connections.removeAll(*c);
    }
}

void LambdaWrapper::helperConnection(QObject* receiver) {
    receivers << receiver;
    if (receiver) QObject::connect(receiver, &QObject::destroyed, this, &LambdaWrapper::disconnectReceiver);
}
```

So, all you have to do is to instantiate this class into your main `QWidget`, `QMainWindow` or `QDialog` derivative.

```
foo.h
....
class Foo : public QMainWindow
....
private:
    LambdaWrapper* lw;
....

foo.cpp
.... 
lw = new LambdaWrapper(this);
QCheckBox *ck = new QCheckBox("check");
lw->connect(ck, &QAbstraceButton::toggled, [=](bool b){ /* do stuff */}, 0);
....
```

The 4th argument of connect member is optional and represents some QObject pointer which is called inside the lambda (and that can crash the program if the lambda is called with this object already deleted). If you pass this argument, its destroyed signal will be connected to a slot in LambdaWrapper which ensures that all connections to this receiver will be disconnected when this receiver is destroyed.

It's pretty dirty but solves my problem. Now I can connect to lambdas straightforward and don't have to worry about disconnecting them.